# Editing the models fields to required specification :)

Tags: python, django

Here I am making a basic MCQ(multiple choice question) using Django. So I created two models question and option, here are the models

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_id=models.IntegerField(default=170)
  question_text=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text


class Options(models.Model):
  question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  options=models.CharField(max_length=500)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.options
```

How can I limit the number of options that added to the question, and giving the user a notification that there should be a minimum number of options for a question?For example, limit the number of options to 5 and minimum number of questions to four

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using client-side validation, or a validation in `views`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the model's [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

```
def clean(self):
    super(Options, self).clean()
    if self.question.options_set.exclude(pk=self.pk).count() > 4:
        raise ValidationError("There can only be 5 Options per Question")
```

And for `Question` accordingly. If all instances are created via the admin or some `ModelForm`, this should be enough. If you create instances programmatically, you need to call `clean()` in `save()`:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.clean()
    super(Options, self).save(**kwargs)
```

You could still `bulk_create` more instances, but for most cases, this should suffice.